# What does 'Refused to get unsafe header "X-Bandwidth-Est 3"' error mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

I have a problem with every website that I am working on currently. And the error is this:

Refused to get unsafe header "X-Bandwidth-Est 3" in base.js.
Base.js is youtube file. I searched a lot and I couldn't find this error. Anyone have idea what this error is?

And this is image of this error:

[image: And this is image of this error]

Comment: This is [CORS issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

Comment: Laravel and PHP tags are not relevant here.

Comment: It started to happen right now after Google Chrome update. This is in a Firebase/Firestore project to me.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey In my case I see two possibilities if it is CORS, the latest Crome update today or some changes in Firebase/Firestore (I am running locally, ie "firebase serve", when I see this.)

Comment: Please add a CORS tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the same problem. It is quite irritating when you try to debug since you get a lot of them.

Are you using Google Chrome? There was an update to it today.

I am also using the YouTube player (which I think you do to).

Unfortunately I don't think I can test in another browser right now, since there are bugs in the other browsers.

EDIT: I ruled out that this is a problem with Firebase/Firestore (since you do not mention them and we got this problem at the same time). So I see two possibilities now, Chrome and YouTube.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome, Safari and Firefox. The version of Google Chrome is 62.0.3202.94. I am using youtube on 3 or 4 sites and I am getting same error. I don't see a error on Firefox and Safari, so the Google Chrome is problem.

Comment: @VeselinKontić Thanks, I see. So which one of us will report this as a Chrome bug? (I have reported a lot of them, but stopped since they put some novice to scanning the bugs.)

Comment: @VeselinKontić Hm, my version of Chrome is "Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)". Did you get an update today?

Comment: You can report bug to Google

Comment: Ok, I will do it tonight. (If they have not fixed the problem then. I guess they are doing a lot of debugging...;-) )

Comment: It turned out to be a YouTube bug (see my bug report). And it looks like it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

All points for a chrome issue, specially because if you go to the youtube.com page and open any video, you will get the same error.